# Need Help on understanding substr c++

Tags: c++, string

I'm very new to programming so please correct me if I'm wrong

strand1.substr(*starting position*,*ending position*)

If I have this code:

```
int main()
{
    string strand1 = "abcde";
    int pos = 1;
    string strand2 = strand1.substr(0, pos);
    cout << strand2;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I expect this output
**ab**

But I only got the first letter as an output
**a**

Comment: The second parameter is [`count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) not "ending position".

Comment: As @user657267 says, [here's the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr).

Comment: @user657267 i worked it out and this answers my questions! :/ cant marked this answered thou because you answered it in the comments

Comment: @user657267 Please post an answer, even if it's as simple as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user657267 points out in the comments, [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) takes two parameters: the starting position, and the length; **not** the ending position.

Thus if you wish to get "ab" from "abcde", you need to have the following:

```
std::string strand1 = "abcde";
auto strand2 = strand1.substr(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
string.substr(start position, length of the string);
```

so, try this,

```
string strand2 = strand1.substr(0, 2);
```